# Collapse AppBarLayout and then disable CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have a `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout` in my activity's layout, sometimes I need to collapse my `AppbarLayout` and then prevent `CollapsingToolbarLayout` to expand with **scrolling**.

I did this:

```
appBarLayout.setExpanded(false);

AppBarLayout.LayoutParams params = (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams)
                                   collapsingToolbarLayout.getLayoutParams();
params.setScrollFlags(AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_SNAP);
collapsingToolbarLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

This code collapsed my `AppBarLayout`:

```
appBarLayout.setExpanded(false);
```

but rest of code, will expand it again and then disable my `CollapsingToolbarLayout`.

**Is there any solution?**

Comment: You could call "mRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)", but as I've noticed , it can cause issues